# Does increase in position uncertainty mean decrease in momentum uncertainty?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Suppose free particle described by Gauss wave-packet. With increasing time the uncertainty in position is increasing and particle is moving in x-direction.

Does the increase in position uncertainty mean decrease in momentum uncertainty?

I would suppose that it does not decrease since uncertainty principle is satisfied without such decrease. But would like to see some actual "proof" or direction from which I would be able to derive it.

Comment: Well, did you try to calculate it for a free particle?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the step you can use to see it:

- Find out the propagator for the free particle i.e. $U(t)$.
- Find out it's matrix element in position basis i.e. $U(x,t;x')\equiv \langle x|U|x'\rangle$.
- Suppose a gaussian wave packet $\psi(x',0)$.
- See it's evolution using propagator i.e.
  $$\psi(x,t)=\int U(x,t;x') \psi(x',0)dx'$$
- Find out the propabability density.
  $$P(x,t)=|\psi(x,t)|^2$$
- find out $\Delta X(t)$ and see it's evolution.

---

This is what you will find for gaussian wave function. The uncertainity in position will grow as time will pass. This is a reflection of the fact that any uncertainity in the initial velocity (that is to say, the momentum) will be reflected with passing time as a growing uncertainity in position.